# += works but ++

Tags: javascript, increment

In my Javascript code **+=** increments the number but **++** doesn't. Could somebody explain why?

Doesn't increment

```
words[splitted[i]] = ( typeof words[splitted[i]] != 'undefined' ) 
                       ? words[splitted[i]]++ 
                       : 1
```

Does increment

```
words[splitted[i]] = ( typeof words[splitted[i]] != 'undefined' ) 
                       ? words[splitted[i]] += 1 
                       : 1
```

Sample code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/2hzHM/3/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=preincrement+postincrement

Comment: @Praveen: I left the one that works ....

Comment: `A ? (words[splitted[i]]+1) : C`

Comment: Because I didn't know it exist. I like the best though :-)

Comment: This kind of confusion is why Douglas Crockford advises against using pre/postincrement. Hence, it gives you a warning in jslint. You could just use: `words[splitted[i]] = ( typeof words[splitted[i]] != 'undefined' ) ? words[splitted[i]]+1 : 1` in this case, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, in a simpler form, will potentially result in code of this form when `words[splitted[i]]` is defined:

```
x = x++;
```

`x++` returns the value of x, and *then* increments it, and then sets the value returned to `x`. This contrasts with

```
x = ++x;
```

where x is incremented first and then evaluated.

To see how this works, look at the following code:

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
z = 1;
x = x++;
y = ++y;
z = z += 1;
alert(x); // 1
alert(y); // 2
alert(z); // 2
```

In any case, I think what you are really wanting to do is something along these lines:

```
(typeof words[splitted[i]] !== 'undefined') ? 
    words[splitted[i]]++ : 
    words[splitted[i]] = 1;
```

This is more lines, but might be more readable:

```
if (typeof words[splitted[i]] !== 'undefined') {
  words[splitted[i]] = 0
}
words[splitted[i]]++;
```

Comment: If I move the `++` before `words[splitted[i]]` it works ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving the `++` to the left side.

```
var number = 1;
number = ++number;
>>> 2
```

The reason the position of the `++` makes a difference, is because on the right side, you're doing an assignment, then an increment of the right hand side value. When the operator is on the left, you're doing an increment then assignment.

Comment: So `words_counter++` is the same like `words_counter = ++words_counter;`

Comment: :-) so what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp, - check the ++ operator section

```
x=++y -> x=6, y=6
x=y++ -> x=5, y=6
```